# Windows 10 COM Port stopped working randomly

Tags: .net, windows, windows-10, port

I have WPF application doing serial printing via COM port(COM1). Everything works fine, and the code is in production on a windows 10 machine.

However, We started getting complaints from our clients that sometimes(roughly once in a week) app is failing to start printing via port. Getting invalid port error.

When the user disable the port via device manager and restart the machine and enable the port again, everything start working. I have no clue whats happening here. is there anything wrong with my serial printing code - no idea.

Anyone experienced similar? please help

Comment: What do you mean by "COM port" in the first place? There are no such ports on machines released in the last 10 years (more or less). What's available are actually USB serial devices, mainly used for POS systems. Nobody else uses serial ports for printing. Without the proper driver these won't work. This isn't a programming question or about Windows. The manufacturer's driver may be buggy. The device may be buggy.

Comment: Are you sure that the port is closed every time after it is used? What is the exact error message - is it one that is generated by your program or does it come from .NET?

Comment: Have you tried disabling and re-enabling the driver *without* restarting the machine? If this works, this is probably a driver error. It's possible some counter overflows once a week. If you have to restart the machine, the problem may be the serial device. When you restart the machine you also restart the device. You could test that by unplugging and re-connecting the device

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos PC with the serial port is in stock https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/desktop-computers/precision-5820-tower-workstation/spd/precision-5820-workstation/xctopt5820corexemea

Comment: @rotabor as an optional in a $2K workstation. That actually proves my point. I doubt that workstation is used to print to POS printers

Comment: If you are very far away from using of serial ports, please do not drop neither question not answers.

Comment: @rotabor quite the opposite - I've used multiserials to talk to 4 wireless sets at a time, used POS printers and I have a couple of horror stories about the bugs in the reference drivers provided by hardware vendors. One of these, which was actually Windows-certified, didn't even run the MSDN C examples because it could handle RTS/CTS automatically. That multiserial vendor refused to admit the bug (programmer error!) until we pointed them to the actual MSDN doc example

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos do not be limited by the area of your interests/professional applications. The serial port is the gate from the virtual world to the real life. Serial ports are still in use in many many applications.

Comment: I have this problem in some of clients from few months ago. but now it is changed. my application cannot communicate with our device. In this situation serial port sending data well and sending buffer show 0, but it didn't received by device until application is open. by closing application device will receive all data and perform well. I think some windows 10 update may caused this problem. did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I watched Windows 10 can arbitrarily reassign ports. So in case of invalid port error, I can recommend enlisting available ports and try to use any available.